# Github branch protection questions and codeowners file

Tags: github, github-codeowners

I have several questions on Github security

(1) For protected branches, is the Maintain Role, and the Admin role the only ones that can merge to it? I noticed Write can't do it.

(2) If I had a Team that had Maintain Access to my repo, why would I need  that same team in CODEOWNERS file for approval?  What is the use-case for using CODEOWNERS file then?

(3) Is there any way to enforce approval from the CODEOWNERS file, and not users who have WRITE or MAINTAIN access? Seems like those two groups can approve a PR also.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first point ("For protected branches, is the Maintain Role, and the Admin role the only ones that can merge to it?"), since Feb. 2023, you have a new option/role:

> ### [Manage branch protection rules with a new permission](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-02-08-manage-branch-protection-rules-with-a-new-permission) (Feb. 2023)
>
> You can now [create a custom role](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-peoples-access-to-your-organization-with-roles/managing-custom-repository-roles-for-an-organization#repository) to manage branch protections without having to grant the Admin role.
> Previously, to manage branch protections you had to be an Admin which provides additional permissions that may not be needed.
> For tighter control of Admin permissions, you can now craft a custom role that has the **Edit repository rules** permission, allowing just the right amount of access.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/7575792/215608072-49f28961-f372-445b-8575-dded7ab7df2a.png?ssl=1 -- Image of Custom roles that shows the new Edit Repository Rules permission]
>
> This permission grants the ability to *create*, *edit*, and *delete* both **[branch protection rules](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule)** and **[protected tags](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/configuring-tag-protection-rules)**.
>
> For more information, visit [Managing custom repository roles for an organization](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-peoples-access-to-your-organization-with-roles/managing-custom-repository-roles-for-an-organization) in the GitHub documentation.
>
> We appreciate feedback on this in GitHub's [public feedback discussions](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/categories/repositories).